# Can I determine when to install webextensions firefox addon to a page?

Tags: javascript, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-webextensions

I wrote a firefox addon use webextensions tech. By default firefox load the addon when the page loaded over. But some pages hava slowly loaded js,like some ads or statistics code, so the addon will not load if I stop the unnecessary page load. Or wait a long time before the addon loaded.

So can I setup the addon loaded time? (example: Before the page loaded)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out the `run_at` option in the content_scripts' [manifest options](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/WebExtensions/manifest.json/content_scripts). For example, you may use the following options:

```
content_scripts": [
  {
    "js": ["my-script.js"],
    "matches": ["https://example.org/"],
    "match_about_blank": true,
    "run_at": "document_start"
  }
]
```

Comment: Be aware that, as a consequence, the `document` at the time the script is loaded will be empty. The DOM structure won't be parsed yet.

Comment: Yes, and also I have noticed that when you run scripts and the `document_start` some performance issues will arrive in the way!

Comment: When you try to load the content script in the same time that the FF tries to load the page, may you experience some delay. So, be careful and load only the necessary parts of your scripts at the start up.